# getting 3rd-party SW that can only write ASCII output to write binary data

Tags: vbscript, io, binary, ascii

**Question**

How can I make a program, capable of writing output files exclusively in ASCII, able to write binary data (specifically, 32-bit float)?

- How I envision the best answer:  some technique to encode a float value to ASCII characters such that the program can write that ASCII-encoded value (to a .txt file) and the resulting .txt, renamed to a .bin, has the byte structure set up so that it can then be directly read as binary (preferably float32 or float16, big- or little-endian).
- How I envision a workaround:  a technique to write the ASCII values to, say, a .vbs or .bat file which can then be launched through a system call from within the program.  The .vbs/.bat/etc. would take the (hard-coded from ASCII) values and write them out in the desired binary format.

---

**Background**

- Details on my setup:  I have a 3rd-party software ("3PSW") application (an industry-standard for optical analysis, FYI) with a convenient macro language that I use to set up long-duration computational analysis.  3PSW can do a system call.  I run it on Windows XP.
- Why the problem is significant:  (A) It takes longer to write the output data in say a large 1000x1000 matrix, and this IO bottleneck is limiting the scope of what we can study with 3PSW (B) the ASCII output takes up significantly more disk space than binary, (C) I need the 3PSW's output to be in a specific binary format in order to be read by another program.
- My present workaround:  I have MATLAB scripts to read the ASCII output and write it out in the desired binary format.  While this establishes functionality, the reformat/rewrite step introduces even more time in the procedure, and sometimes MATLAB & 3PSW both hang due to RAM memory usage.  Computational duration costs are limiting the granularity with which we can explore our solution space, compromising the quality of our results.  Having the reformat done by say VBSCRIPT instead of RAM-intensive MATLAB would decrease the chance that MATLAB &/or 3PSW hang due to memory, even if not impacting duration.
- I have notified 3PSW's vendor regarding this and am at their mercy whether they plan to include it in a future release.

---

Any help/suggestion/guidance/redirection is most welcome, as is your time in consideration.  Thank you.

Comment: Powershell (or even a VB.NET or C# executable) would be a better choice than vbscript.

Comment: Thank you.  I think that if I made (w/in 3PSW) a system call string to some external script (Powershell, etc.), with values of the 1000x1000 matrix as arguments, that script could then write/append values to a binary file.  Even if that script was limited to some number (say 256) of input arguments, I could iterate until I wrote out the entire matrix.  That technique just may avoid the IO duration cost (of having to write an ASCII output) even if a residual duration cost is incurred from iterative system-calling.  Please let me know pitfalls/constraints immediately apparent with this approach.

Comment: Can't think of any offhand.  You will need some expertise in the binary format; presumably it's something standard.  And some expertise in the language of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you want is possible without rewriting the application. If the application is capable of writing its output to STDOUT instead of to a file you could implement a filter that transforms the ASCII data stream to a binary stream before writing it to a file, but that's about it.

Comment: Thank you, deeper access to 3PSW's inner workings is likely necessary to make any progress.  I think having 3PSW do a system call to say a binary-writing-capable Powershell script, with floating values as input arguments, may have the most promise (besides pressuring the vendor).  Regarding the original technique, I may try encoding something myself and will share any progress. Thank you.